# Fuzzy Query inside PayloadTermQuery

Tags: lucene

I am new to PayloadTermQuery usage and found it working for simple matches from the example given @ Search Hub.

As with Lucene-4.1,  I couldn't find any API to support Fuzzy Query inside PayloadTermQuery.

Can you help me in understanding why there is restriction on Term specification rather than Query being a parameter to PayloadTermQuery constructor ?

Thanks, 
Manu

Answer (score 0):

FuzzyQuery extends from org.apache.lucene.search.**MultiTermQuery**, whereas PayloadTermQuery accepts a  single Term.

The restriction of being able to pass only 'Term' as the argument is because of the type of query you are constructing, which is Payload **TermQuery**.

In case it allows a Query instance, the constructor will end up with receiving queries that contain multiple terms.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  In fact, I wanted to know the side effects in case if there was a support for Fuzzy inside Payload.  As I see, it would have been really helpful in boosting query terms that need spell checks as well.  As of now, the payload api is restricting me to exact term match cases.