# Using payload boost with FuzzyQuery in Lucene-4.x

Tags: java, lucene, fuzzy-search, payload

Is there any chance to use payload boost as described [here](https://lucidworks.com/blog/getting-started-with-payloads/) with [FuzzyQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_2/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyQuery.html) ? Or maybe one can suggest what is the best strategy to implement a hybrid Fuzzy/Payload search.

Currently I have documents in the index in which certain parts have got higher match priorities using the technique described in the article. Everything goes well until fuzzy queries come to the stage.

Right now I'm planning to hack the Lucene code somehow to be able to adjust terms scoring with payload factor, e.g. in `MultiTermQuery.TopTermsScoringBooleanQueryRewrite.addClause()`. However I'm not sure that this is the best way to resolve the problem.

Please suggest.

Likely [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240203/fuzzy-query-inside-payloadtermquery) has been asked a while ago, but hasn't received a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution.

You should use only PayloadTermQuery, but you can extend your tokens with a unique filter. With this unique filter you can put new simplified terms into a token chain, I mean ascii folded, remove double letters, and so on.... By using PayloadTermQuery you also can devalue the score for new terms.

For me this solution works fine, and really fast. I hope I could help.

Some code from my solution:

```
  private String simplifyingToken(String token) {
    String token = H.foldToAscii(token);
    if(!H.isNumber(token)){
        token = token.replaceAll("(.)\\1", "$1"); //double letters
    }
    token = token.replaceAll("\\-", "");
    token = token.replaceAll("(ou)", "u");
    token = token.replaceAll("(cz)", "c");
    token = token.replaceAll("w", "v");
    return simpleTokenJocker + token; //tf idf correction
}
```

Comment: Well, term filters pertially solve the problem, but only when we can to perform one-to-one conversion. When we need to expand e.g. an asterisk, simple filters w/o lookup into the real index like the one above would lead to an exponential grow of variants. So we have to re-implement index lookup to mimic actual FuzzyQuery behavior

Comment: I agree with you, It is just a simple solution which can help just in simple cases.

Comment: Unfortunately my case isn't a simple one :)

Comment: Try to simplify it :)  Simple solutions mean less problems, and sometimes it is more efficient and useful than complicated ones.